# Recharacterizing a function based on linearity assumption

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

I know that a functional $L:$ $V$-->$W$ is linear if, for any vectors $u$,$v$ in $V$ and any scalars $a$,$b$ in $R$, $L(au+bv)=aL(u)+bL(v)$. The proof I am working on gives me the following function:

$f(x,y,z)=(2x-4y+3z+q, 6x + rxyz)$ where $q,r$ are in $R$. My task is to show that this function is linear if and only if $q=r=0$. I am first going in the "only if" direction, so I'm assuming linearity and trying to show that $r=q=0$.

My question is, how can I recharacterize this equation based on the fact that it's linear? I'm looking at the definition, but I'm not sure how to proceed when there are this many elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the linearity assumption for well-chosen $u,v,a,b$.

> Linearity implies $f(0,0,0)=0$. [Concretely, $L(0u + 0v) = 0 L(u) + 0 L(v) = 0$.] But $f(0,0,0) = (q, 0)$ so $q = 0$.
>  To see that $r=0$, note that linearity implies $2 f(1, 1, 1) = f(2, 2, 2)$.